# php arrays creating dynamically giving incorrect values

Tags: php

I want to create a array with values:
3,2,1.... and I want to use array_push and a forloop.
I have written the following code is not working..

============

```
<?PHP
$temp0=3;
$temp1=2;
$temp2=1;
$temp3=1;
$temp4=1;
$temp5=1;

$arraytemp=array();

for($i=0;$i<4;$i++)
{
$r="temp";
$dd=$r.$i;
array_push($arraytemp,$dd);
}
echo $arraytemp[3];
?>
```

can you please let me know what I am missing

Comment: Your code working fine... what you looking for ?.Your code output : **Array ( [0] => temp0 [1] => temp1 [2] => temp2 [3] => temp3 )**

Comment: @gowri: He needs the value of above declared variables not the variable name itself

Answer (score 0):

This is how should you assign `$dd`

```
for($i=0;$i<4;$i++)
{
  $dd=${"temp".$i};
  array_push($arraytemp,$dd);
}
```

Comment: can you please explan me what does this do:

Comment: `${"temp".$i}` is the way to reference actual value of dynamically generated variable name. Here this will call the value of `temp(n)` variable. You also have an alternate, just do not change your code and add double `$` in front of `dd` in `array_push` line `array_push($arraytemp,$$dd);`

Answer (score 0):

your `$dd` has the name of your var as a string. you want to use this for this technique:

```
array_push($arraytemp,$$dd);
```

Pay attention to the double `$$` :)

What happens here is the following: the `$dd` gets replaced by the string it contains. so your call

```
    array_push($arraytemp,$dd);
```

will do this:

```
   array_push($arraytemp,'temp0');
```

But you want this:

```
   array_push($arraytemp,$temp0);
```

so you need to show you want an acutal `$var` with that name, so you add the `$`. It's just the way the syntax works, neccessairy to distinguish between a normal string and a string that's supposed to be a variable

Comment: Not true! (*goes on a quick editting spree*). All lies!. Ow wait, I mean thanks, i'll fix :)

Answer (score 0):

confusing what do you want to achieve here, do you want to:

create array with value: temp0, temp1, temp2 ...

```
for($i=0;$i<4;$i++){
    array_push($array,"temp{$i}");
}
echo $array[3];
```

create array with value: 0, 1, 2, 3 ..

```
for($i=0;$i<4;$i++){
    array_push($array,$i);
}
echo $array[3];
```

create array with value based on your defined variable above ($temp0, $temp1 ...)

```
$temp0=3;
$temp1=2;
$temp2=1;
$temp3=1;

$array = array();
for($i=0;$i<4;$i++){
    $val = "temp{$i}";
    array_push($array,$$val);
}
echo $array[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way, going by what you're requesting, although you didn't specify how many numbers you wanted to add. so for loop won't work that way. you're best off with a while loop.

```
$foo = array();
$i = 1;
while (some end condition) {
   array_push($foo, $i);
   $i++;
}
print_r($foo);
```